# How to stream a constantly changing image

Tags: python, nginx, raspberry-pi

## The Setup:

I have an NGINX web server. On a web page I am running the javascript to refresh the file `tmp_image.jpg` every half a second:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("x");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    setTimeout(timedRefresh, 500);
};

function timedRefresh() {
    // just change src attribute, will always trigger the onload callback
    try {
        img.src = 'tmp_image.jpg?d=' + Date.now();
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
setTimeout(timedRefresh, 100);
```

With the HTML:

```
<canvas id="x" width="700px" height="500px"></canvas>
```

On another process using a raspberry pi camera I am running a script to write a image to a file `tmp_image.jpg` with the library [picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/):

```
for frame in cam.camera.capture_continuous(raw, format="rgb", use_video_port=True):
    img = frame.array
    cv2.imwrite("tmp_image.jpg", img)
```

## The problem:

I am receiving the error:

> GET http://192.168.1.234/images/tmp_img.jpg?d=1513855080653 net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Which then leads the refresh to crash (even though I have put it in a `try` `catch`)
I believe this is because NGINX is trying to read the file while it is being written to. So what should I do? And is this awfully inefficient?

Comment: Each camera shot you make with picamera has different size. And `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` is caused by difference in actual size of image and the one declared by web server in HTTP header `content-length`. So my advice would be captutring images as a  bitmaps without compression so that all images has the same size.

Comment: would writing as a png instead of a jpg do this?

Comment: Change your `cv2.imwrite("tmp_image.jpg", img)` to write to `fred.jpg` then when it is complete and fully written, rename `fred.jpg` to `tmp_image.jpg`. That way the web server cannot read the file while OpenCV is writing it.

Comment: Keep in mind that putting `img.src = 'tmp_image.jpg?d=' + Date.now();` in `try` `catch` does nothing - it guards only assignment operation which obviously executes without errors.

Comment: @MarkSetchell how would you recommend renaming in python?

Comment: `os.rename("fred.jpg", "tmp_image.jpg")`

Comment: Awesome @MarkSetchell works a treat

Comment: Maintenance programmers of the future may thank you for choosing better names - maybe `fred.jpg` could be `inprogress.jpg` and `tmp_image.jpg` could be `complete.jpg`...